# Visual studio debug child process on its startup

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a WPF Application after it is loading (some WCF services) and I am running a child process (Gui less Windows Application). Both projects are in my solution.

I wish to debug both of them. I know I can debug two projects if I set both of with action = start in the solution properties under "Multiple startup projects".

But this is not the case since the WPF app is starting the child process after X time. And I cannot "Attach to process" since I want to catch the main method of the child process.

Is there a solution?

What I did so far was to disable the `CreateNewProcess()` method, place a breakpoint where it should occur, and manually debug the project, and then continue the WPF app from that breakpoint, using two visual studios.

Answer (score 4):

Use the debugger settings Registry key under

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

as [described in this blog post](http://hmemcpy.com/2010/12/how-to-debug-a-process-that-is-crashing-on-startup/) to make the child process automatically break on startup. Then, when prompted, choose the Visual Studio instance you're using to debug the parent process.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the solution in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing the following extension from the Visual Studio team: [Introducing the Child Process Debugging Power Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx). It is available on the [Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a) for Visual Studio 2013 and above.

It allows automatically attaching child processes to the current debugger, so in your case, the child process started by the WPF app would be attached to the debugger upon launch, and you could therefore easily intercept the main method of the child process.