# Attach VIsual Studio 2019 Debugger to child process automatically

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to automatically attach the VS2019 Debugger to child processes spawned via `System.Diagnostic.Process.Start()` method?

I've tried  [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) to no avail.

My executables are .NET 5 Console applications.

Comment: Do you have mixed mode debugging enabled when debugging your parent process?

Comment: Refer to this thread: [attach a new process manually to the current debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32125477/14324452)